# Modifying "a" tags in a string and return the updated string in javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, ionic-framework

I'm getting string data via a CMS that contains a few anchor links.

I'm going to compiling the code into an app (via Ionic Framework) so I need the "a" tags to contain an onClick function that will use the "inappbrowser" Cordova plugin.

So I've set up a function called "processLinks" to send the string to be processed:

```
 <p ng-bind-html="processLinks(data[0].value)"></p>
```

And the function is this:

```
            $scope.processLinks = function (inputText) {
                return inputText.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, "");
            };
```

Currently, this simply removes the links (Which was a temporary solution).

So I need help achieving the following:

I need to send the string into the function, then modify the links by inserting the onClick function with the "href" from each link:

I need to modify:

```
<a href="http://www.thesite.com"></a>
```

to become:

```
<a href="http://www.thesite.com" onclick="window.open('http://www.thesite.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"></a>
```

Then return the processed string.

Comment: It would be much simpler to just create a delegated event handler to capture the clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this new regular expression:

```
$scope.processLinks = function (inputText) {
    return inputText.replace(/(<a.*href="(.*?)".*)(>.*?<\/a>)/gi, '$1 onClick="window.open(\'$2\', \'_system\', \'location=yes\'); return false;"$3');
};
```

A bit explanation: We capture 3 groups from the in put text:

1. The first part of the link, right before the first `>` that closing `<a`
2. The link
3. The second part of the link, start with `>` until the end of the link.

Then we assemble the result by joining 3 above groups with the `onClick...`.

At least it works for your example ;-)